# Preston stops following me after retaking the castle

Tags: fallout-4

I've just completed the mission to retake the castle for the Minutemen. Preston was my follower before the mission, then left when it started to go to the meeting point.

After completing the mission he returned to Sanctuary and I can no longer speak to him, does anyone know if this is a bug, or there are subsequent quests I must complete to get him to follow me again?

**Edit**

I've since finished the old guns quest and I spoke to him to collect the reward but couldn't bring up any extra dialog with him.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily switching to another follower?  Sometimes this will reset a broken follower back to a 'normal' state.

Comment: Yeah still no luck unfortunately

Comment: You can definitely get him as a follower again. I don't recall there being a gap, but I wasn't using him the whole time. Did you do the missions in the Castle afterward, finding the armory and setting up artillery?

Comment: I've just finished the artillery mission, I'll see if I can recruit him again

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/244371/21177

Answer (score 4):

There's a workaround [in the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Preston_Garvey#Bugs): (WARNING: Wiki is full of spoilers; I've copied the section below and censored spoilers)

> ### Bugs
>
> - There is a known bug where after the quest to reclaim the Castle it becomes impossible to get him as a companion. Wait until dealing with
>     *[SPOILER]* and visit the *[Brotherhood of Steel]* before completing the quest, so
>     this bug does not affect the Sole Survivor.
>
>   - This can be fixed on PC by opening the console, selecting Preston Garvey and inputting:
>       **removefac 00075d56**

I've read somewhere that all this faction code does is block companion capabilities, which makes little sense as the last line of dialogue for him is that he'll always have my back.

Anyway, you have two options (unless you play on PS4/Xbox One, in which case #1 is your only option):

1. If possible, reload a save right before taking the castle and continue with the main quest, until you "clear" the location Fort Hagen; or
2. Open the console, click Preston and type the command.

I used the console command and I didn't see any side-effects, even a little further in the main quest. I still highly recommend doing a full save (manual one, not auto/quick) before doing this. You can also restart the game afterwards to ensure the game state is stable. (Though that's really not needed and mostly voodoo on my part)