# Why won't Preston Garvey follow me back to the castle?

Tags: fallout-4

I started [the castle mission for the Minutemen](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Taking_Independence) too early and was not able to complete the mission. **After I fought the mirelurks and destroyed every last one of the eggs, I left mid-mission to do other quests.** I traveled to Mass Pike Interchange with Preston and another companion and now Preston is stuck at Mass Pike Interchange

**Now, when I try to go back, it tells me I must destroy all the egg clusters. Can anyone help me with this?** I've already tried leaving the area and waiting a few days, but he's still stuck.

Comment: No I hav not tried that. How do I do that, just keep sleeping or....?

Comment: It didn't work and he still in the same spot how ever I waited the period of time and the spot where he froze reset but he was still there. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yea I fought the miralurks and destroyed every last one of the eggs. And I traveled to Mass Pike Interchange with Preston and another companion and know Preston is stuck at Mass Pile Interchange

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243825/21177

Comment: I edited in some details from comments here. Comments may be deleted at any time, so it helps to put relevant information in the question.

Comment: Just curious have you fought the castle boss yet?

Comment: If Preston is your companion you can try dismissing him to sanctuary and then picking him up again.

Answer (score 1):

You said you destroyed all of the eggs, is it possible you only destroyed the ones in the courtyard and missed the ones on the inside of the castle? If this is the case perhaps you have not completed the quest and the game is not working properly. Little tip, I would advance well armed and with power armor.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. Your badges indicate you've already reviewed the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour). I'm not going to downvote, though, so as to not slow down you getting to 50 rep, where you'll be able to [comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on other people's posts.